# Post file using webclient webflux to API accepting APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to upload file to rest api using Webflux web client. the API which accepts the file has content type as `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` how i can do this using spring `WebClient`?

how can i convert below curl to `WebClient` request ?

```
curl -i -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --header --data-binary @myfile.pdf  https://some-host/some-url
```

**Note** - I am not expecting very large file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i was able to upload file

**Step 1**  : Read file as bytes array

```
bytes = new FileSystemResource((filePath)).getInputStream()
                    .readAllBytes();
```

**Step 2**  : pass the byte array to `bodyValue` method

```
webClient.post()
         .uri("Some-uri)
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
         .bodyValue(bytes)
         .retrieve()
         .toBodilessEntity())
```